# Conditional flag if a windows service should start or not

Tags: c#, windows, service

I am currently working on a project (c# / for windows platforms), that requires a service to do a specific task. The service will be installed on multiple remote machines, that may not be connected to any sort of network / internet.

Right now the service is starting automatically when a machine is turned on, as it should. However once the service has completed its task I don't want it to start repeating the task again. The machines may be turned on and off multiple times. It's also possible that the service finishes its defined task when the machines have already turned on / off many times before.

I was wondering if it's possible to somehow set a flag / condition within the service. Ideally the service would check at the start if a flag is set and if so the service should just terminate itself.

Currently I have solved this as following: Once the service has finished the task the service then writes an empty "flag.txt" file in a specified folder. At every start it first checks if a "flag.txt" file exists and if the flag.txt file exists the service terminates. However, I feel like this is a very bad approach and I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to solve this problem.

Comment: Maybe you can use a registry key for that. Then at least it's a little bit more "hidden". I was also looking but have not been able to find it: I am 80% sure, there was a "start-once" option somewhere ... it's been a while since I handcrafted my last service, though.

Comment: Is the program should only ever be executed once in its lifetime, then a service is not the  right approach.  That should be used for a program that needs to run in the background multiple times.  You should simply execute a program on start-up, and then it should remove itself from the startup execution when finished.

Comment: Maybe I am confusing that with an option of the Windows Task Scheduler... which has _a lot_ of different options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Windows Registry to store a flag or configuration value. Your service can check this value at startup and decide whether to proceed with the task. If the value is set to "completed," the service can terminate itself. Here's an example of how to write and read a registry value in C#:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;

// Writing the flag in the Registry
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\YourAppName");
key.SetValue("Flag", "Completed");

// Reading the flag from the Registry
var flag = (string)key.GetValue("Flag");
if (flag == "Completed")
{
    // Terminate the service
}
```